# orientDB list of map keys

Tags: sql, orientdb

I created an embedded map trough Java in the following way:

```
Map<String,Object> mapObjectToInsert = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    mapObjectToInsert.put("attr1",1);
    mapObjectToInsert.put("attr2","bla");

    ODocument doc = new ODocument("testClass");
    doc.field("postUrl","11");
    doc.field("jsonData",mapObjectToInsert);
    doc.save();
```

and now I have the following embedded map:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#14:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "testClass",
        "postUrl": "11",
        "postCategory": "#13:37",
        "postDateImported": "2015-04-28 15:10:38",
        "isBusniess": false,
        "isPaid": false,
        "postDateRead": "2015-04-28 15:10:33",
        "jsonData": {
            "attr1":"1"
            "attr2":"bla"            
        },
        "@fieldTypes": "postCategory=x,postDateImported=t,postDateRead=t"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.166 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
```

}

I have found that

```
select expand(jsonData) from testClass
```

Gives the following (the **values** of the map):

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "value": "bla"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed in 0.159 sec. Returned 2 record(s)"
```

}

But I want to be able to get the **keys** names from **jsonData** (attr1 and attr2)
What is the method to do so?
Thank you!

Comment: It will be easier to help if, instead of printing the result from a query, you give a sequence of commands to achieve your current state.

Comment: What do you mean? Im having embbeddMap with key-value's and i want to retrive all the keys..

Comment: I believe that, in order to solve the problem, people will have to reproduce it. And they'll do it way faster with a sequence of creates/inserts. Don't you agree? :) [same for your previous question]

Comment: I edited and added a sample code from the java application, i hope it make things more clear :)

Comment: Yes :) Using SQL or Java API?

Comment: I Will need to get the keys trough php, so SQL syntax please :)

Comment: I don't know. With Java you can: `ODocument doc = db.load(new ORecordId("#11:0")); Map<String, Object> map = doc.field("jsonData"); keys = map.keySet());` . Maybe you'll find a similar way to do this using PHP driver.

Comment: Thank you! but in this example i have only 1 record and so its possible to o it the way you showed, but i aiming for thousands of records..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
select jsonData.keys() from testClass
```